# Custom Post Types and 404 Pages

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have tried refreshing my permalinks but I still cant get this to work correctly.

I have the categories `movies`, `gaming`, `blu-ray`, and `tv` already created, so my URLs are `site.com/movies/` for example.  I would like for a post for movies to be at `site.com/movies/post-here/` so for my custom post type my slug is `movies.

All my normal wordpress psots under the category `movies` are now 404ing while posts created specifically from the post type `Movie Posts` is working fine. Is this normal? Is there a step I'm not including?

Here are all my custom post types (Created with Custom Post Type UI):

```
//Movies Custom Post Type
register_post_type('movies_cp', array(  'label' => 'Movie Posts','description' => '','public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'show_in_menu' => true,'capability_type' => 'post','hierarchical' => false,'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movies'),'query_var' => true,'exclude_from_search' => false,'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes',),'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag',),'labels' => array (
  'name' => 'Movie Posts',
  'singular_name' => 'Movie Post',
  'menu_name' => 'Movie Posts',
  'add_new' => 'Add Movie Post',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add New Movie Post',
  'edit' => 'Edit',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit Movie Post',
  'new_item' => 'New Movie Post',
  'view' => 'View Movie Post',
  'view_item' => 'View Movie Post',
  'search_items' => 'Search Movie Posts',
  'not_found' => 'No Movie Posts Found',
  'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Movie Posts Found in Trash',
  'parent' => 'Parent Movie Post',
),) );


//Gaming Custom Post Type
register_post_type('gaming_cp', array(  'label' => 'Gaming Posts','description' => '','public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'show_in_menu' => true,'capability_type' => 'post','hierarchical' => false,'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'gaming'),'query_var' => true,'exclude_from_search' => false,'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes',),'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag',),'labels' => array (
  'name' => 'Gaming Posts',
  'singular_name' => 'Gaming Post',
  'menu_name' => 'Gaming Posts',
  'add_new' => 'Add Gaming Post',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add New Gaming Post',
  'edit' => 'Edit',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit Gaming Post',
  'new_item' => 'New Gaming Post',
  'view' => 'View Gaming Post',
  'view_item' => 'View Gaming Post',
  'search_items' => 'Search Gaming Posts',
  'not_found' => 'No Gaming Posts Found',
  'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Gaming Posts Found in Trash',
  'parent' => 'Parent Gaming Post',
),) );


//Blu-ray Custom Post Type
register_post_type('blu-ray_cp', array( 'label' => 'Blu-Ray Posts','description' => '','public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'show_in_menu' => true,'capability_type' => 'post','hierarchical' => false,'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'blu-ray'),'query_var' => true,'exclude_from_search' => false,'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes',),'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag',),'labels' => array (
  'name' => 'Blu-Ray Posts',
  'singular_name' => 'Blu-Ray Post',
  'menu_name' => 'Blu-Ray Posts',
  'add_new' => 'Add Blu-Ray Post',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add New Blu-Ray Post',
  'edit' => 'Edit',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit Blu-Ray Post',
  'new_item' => 'New Blu-Ray Post',
  'view' => 'View Blu-Ray Post',
  'view_item' => 'View Blu-Ray Post',
  'search_items' => 'Search Blu-Ray Posts',
  'not_found' => 'No Blu-Ray Posts Found',
  'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Blu-Ray Posts Found in Trash',
  'parent' => 'Parent Blu-Ray Post',
),) );


//TV Custom Post Type
register_post_type('tv_cp', array(  'label' => 'TV Posts','description' => '','public' => true,'show_ui' => true,'show_in_menu' => true,'capability_type' => 'post','hierarchical' => false,'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'tv'),'query_var' => true,'exclude_from_search' => false,'supports' => array('title','editor','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','thumbnail','author','page-attributes',),'taxonomies' => array('category','post_tag',),'labels' => array (
  'name' => 'TV Posts',
  'singular_name' => 'TV Post',
  'menu_name' => 'TV Posts',
  'add_new' => 'Add TV Post',
  'add_new_item' => 'Add New TV Post',
  'edit' => 'Edit',
  'edit_item' => 'Edit TV Post',
  'new_item' => 'New TV Post',
  'view' => 'View TV Post',
  'view_item' => 'View TV Post',
  'search_items' => 'Search TV Posts',
  'not_found' => 'No TV Posts Found',
  'not_found_in_trash' => 'No TV Posts Found in Trash',
  'parent' => 'Parent TV Post',
),) );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a page that has the permalink /movies/ too? Because the duplicate of the permalink may be the cause of your 404 error.

Comment: Can you try to modify your category name? Dont modify your custom post type name if you have post in it because it will delete them.